# RoR 3.0.9 - Passing a variable from routes.rb to application_controller.rb or viceversa

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a multi site project that changes from one to another by changing two variables, one is inside routes.rb and the other in application_controller.rb. Is it possible to pass variables between these files so that I only have to change a parameter to achieve the change required?

On my routes.rb file I use this variable to assign the correct controller the routes it should use. For example:

```
def showsite
  "mysite1"
end
root :to => "#{showsite}#index"
```

And on application_controller.rb I use the same parameter to get the domain of the site, some layouts it should use and another things. For example:

```
before_filter :set_defaults
def showsite
  "mysite1"
end
def set_defaults
  if "#{showsite}" == "mysite1"
    @domain = 'mysite1.com'
  elsif "#{showsite}" == "mysite2"
    @domain = 'mysite2.com'
  else
    @domain.nil?
  end
end
def special_layout
  "#{showsite}"
end
```

Every time I want to show a different version of the project I need to change two variables. I know its not a lot but I have to do it many times a day. Im pretty new on RoR, if there is a better solution please guide me to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [Rails Initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files). E.g. the following:

```
File: `config/initializers/showsite.rb`
```

with the following content:

```
MyApp::Application.config.showsite = 'mysite1'
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
def showsite
  MyApp::Application.config.showsite
end
```

and similar in your routes file.

Comment: It shows "undefined method for 'showsite'...". I added the same line to config/enviroment.rb and its working. Thanks!